# How to run Python Script from mono/monodevelop

Tags: c#, python, mono, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run the following python script using C# and MonoDevelop and execute the code.
My Mono Develop code

```
        string command = "python";
        string argss = "/home/xyz/script.py A_file B_file";
        string verb = "";
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procInfo.FileName = command;  
        procInfo.Arguments = argss;    
        procInfo.Verb = verb;         
        Process.Start(procInfo);
```

The above code is not working. It is showing A_file & B_File are not accessible.
even A_File & B_File has been give full permission & file is placed at same location.
python script is working correctly when compile directly on terminal.
I am running MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Comment: Without the actual error it is difficult to say. I would guess that you need to set the working directory for the ProcessStartInfo to be the same as the directory containing the A_file and B_file files so the script can find these files.

Comment: All the file are in same location, then also both file are not accessible

Comment: What is the error? What is the working directory when you run it from the command line?

Comment: error : can't open A_file.sh

Comment: I would print out the working directory from the python script

Comment: Can you add a `import os; print(os.getcwd())` at the top of your Python script? That way you can see with what path the script is executed and as such where it expects the files to be.